# Split user input and add character in Python string

Tags: python, string, csv, crystal-reports

I have a Python script that accepts user input (it is scanned with a barcode) that subsequently generates a CSV file with all of the user's data. This CSV file is then used to drive a Crystal Report.

The input consists of a single string of concatenated fields delimited by a space- Item #, Lot #, and Quantity.

```
    Example: G00177 LOT12345 24
```

The problem, however, is that the Item # OR Lot # could potentially be numeric instead of a string:

```
    Example 1: G00177 12345 24
    Example 2: 00177 12345 24
```

My thought was to append a character to the beginning of the Item # and Lot #, forcing it into a string, and then using Crystal to automatically suppress the added character.

So far, I have only been able to add a character to the beginning of the Item #- not the Lot #. I also do not want to append to the Quantity field as it will always be numeric.

Any criticism, insight, or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I am just learning with Python and I know my approach is not the best.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The format of the string in your first code block is different than the second. Why is one `Example:` while the other is `Example #:`?

Comment: @HuuNguyen, thats not actually part of the code, just OP denoting examples

Comment: Couldn't you just typecast it as a str() if you need it to be a string and then pass it along? Unless it needs a letter in the beginning in order to be able to understand what it wants.

Comment: Bob- I cast the user's data as a str, and then split on a " ". My issue is that Crystal is trying to be "intelligent" by automatically dictating my Lot # as a string or numeric field. My goal is to append a character to the first 2 delimited fields (Item / Lot #) while leaving the last field (Quantity) as numeric. I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
report_one = '00177 12345 24'
report_two = 'G0177 12345 24'
report_three = 'G0177 I2345 24'

def convert(original):
    s = original.split()
    for i in range(2):       # 2 is used here because that's how many 'words'
        try:                 #     we want to check for numeric-ness. This can
            int(s[i])        #     be adjusted if you have to change your schema
        except ValueError:   #     at some point in the future.
            s[i] += 'S'
    return ' '.join(s)

print convert(report_one)    # Prints 00177 12345 24
print convert(report_two)    # Prints G0177S 12345 24
print convert(report_three)  # Prints G0177S I2345S 24
```

This first splits up the string into its individual words. You know that the first and the second ones are potentially integers, and you need a way for the next system to understand them as strings.

Using the split words, doing a cast on the word into an `int` under a `try` block will throw a `ValueError` if the string is not an integer. That is, if it contains any letters, the `except ValueError` clause will kick in. At this point, you can simply append a letter to the end, and have your next system scan the word for that ending letter (here my example uses an `'S'`).

If you want to append a letter to the beginning, you can replace `s[i] += 'S'` with: `s[i] = 'S' + s[i]`

Comment: Great thoughts, thank you for the fast reply! I will play around with this.

What are your thoughts on simply using replace? Or maybe rsplit?

        bt1Replace = bt1.replace(' ',' `')

I am wondering if there is a way to append a character after the first 2 delimiters, but skip the 3rd since Quantity will always be numeric.

Again, any thought or insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: I get your concern. I've edited my answer to clarify what my code does. It already addresses your point about not replacing Quantity.

Comment: Now I see. This looks like it will work if I tailor it accordingly! Thanks again Huu!

Comment: this worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your help. I hope to one day be able to pay it forward.